# Maintaining different python versions for virtual environments

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, virtualenv, python-venv

I have 2 different versions of python. 1 is always used with my anaconda and it is 3.9.7.

For the vs code, I tend to change the versions according to need.
Currently I have a project which requires me to use tensorflow 1.5-1.7 for which I require python 3.5 or 3.6 max. I have tried installing python 3.6 and then I create a virtual environment with it.
I try installing tenosrflow 1.5 using the below given command

```
pip install tensorflow==1.5
```

I get the error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.5 (from versions: 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1, 2.5.0rc2, 2.5.0rc3, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.5

Is there any way available to maintain 2 different python version as I need to keep both.

Comment: You mentioned that you are using anaconda, so please have a look at https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html Maybe you forgot to activate your environment.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing, but here's the thing.
I need separate environment for anaconda and vs code.